# pm2 fails on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, raspberry-pi, pm2

I'm trying to install `pm2`on a Raspberry pi. I did it with `sudo npm install -g pm2`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo npm install -g pm2
/usr/bin/pm2 -> /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
/usr/bin/pm2-dev -> /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-dev
/usr/bin/pm2-docker -> /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-docker
/usr/bin/pm2-runtime -> /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-runtime
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.1 (node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"})

+ pm2@4.1.2
updated 3 packages in 16.284s
```

However, when I run pm2, I have the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pm2 start script.sh
/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/has-flag/index.js:1
24 �ubelet.goz0t4] node "rispberrypy-1# not found
   ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/supports-color/index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

In this example I ran `pm2 start` but I have the same error with any of the `pm2` commands

Do you know what is this error and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

pm2 requires that you start a *node.js* script. In your provided example you are trying to execute `script.sh` with pm2. Try putting the pm2 command in the script and just execute the script :)

Comment: I don't think it's the problem. I have the error also with `pm2 list` for example

Comment: What if you just try and execute the script with node.js? If it works then it could just be that the pm2 installation is somehow corrupted and you can try uninstalling and installing it again.

Comment: the script works fine. Just the pm2 command that fails. I'll uninstall and reinstall it

Comment: Problem solved. I don't know exactly what was the problem, but I uninstall/re-install it two times before it works correctly